# Issues with Types when using reduce on an object

Tags: typescript

I have a function trying to return an object it receives with the keys all Pascal case instead of Camel case.

**My Interfaces:**

```
export interface INodeMailerResponseLower {
    accepted: string[];
    rejected: string[];
    envelopeTime: number;
    messageTime: number;
    messageSize: number;
    response: string;
    messageId: string;
}

export interface INodeMailerResponseUpper {
    Accepted: string[];
    Rejected: string[];
    EnvelopeTime: number;
    MessageTime: number;
    MessageSize: number;
    Response: string;
    MessageId: string;
}
```

**My Code:**

```
import { upperFirst } from 'lodash';

const response: INodeMailerResponseLower;   // << insert object values here
const formattedResponse: INodeMailerResponseUpper = Object.keys(response).reduce((acc, key) => {
     acc[upperFirst(key)] = response[key];
     return acc;
   }, {});
```

**Typescript is giving me the following error message:**

> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'INodeMailerResponseUpper':  Accepted, Rejected, EnvelopeTime, MessageTime, and 3 more.ts(2740)

**Question:**
How do I correctly type my accumulator when doing the reduce?

Comment: Do you have a `upperFirst` function defined? What is its function signature?

Comment: i just added it. upperFirst is an import from lodash. That works as i've tested it separately from this.

Comment: Why are you using a reduce (fold) function? Do you not want upperfirst applied to each element and then use that ? Seems to me like a map or forEach would be more suited.

Comment: @Chai forEach didn't seem good here because the goal was to produce a new object not perform an action on another object. Map returns an array not an object. In a perfect world i'd like to use Object.fromEntries to do this but our application is not ready for es2019.

Comment: Until very recently it was not possible to strictly type this sort of string manipulation, but now you can! https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#intrinsic-string-manipulation-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Partial<INodeMailerResponseUpper>` for the `reduce` type parameter. This will mean `acc` has that type and will allow you to assign properties to it. However, you need to cast the result to `INodeMailerResponseUpper` because TypeScript doesn’t know that the final result will contain all the required properties.

You could do it like this, which uses a fair bit of type assertions:

```ts
const formattedResponse = Objectkeys(response)
    .reduce<Partial<INodeMailerResponseUpper>>((acc, key) => {
        (acc[upperFirst(key) as keyof INodeMailerResponseUpper] as unknown) =
            response[key as keyof INodeMailerResponseLower];
        return acc;
    }, {}) as INodeMailerResponseUpper;
```

Or you could also improve the type of lodash’s `upperFirst` (using TypeScript 4.1):

```ts
declare module 'lodash' {
    interface LoDashStatic {
        upperFirst<S extends string = ''>(string?: S): Capitalize<S>;
    }
}

const formattedResponse = (Object.keys(response) as (keyof INodeMailerResponseLower)[])
    .reduce<Partial<INodeMailerResponseUpper>>((acc, key) => {
        // Without the as unknown, TypeScript would complain that
        // string | number | string[] is not assignable to undefined
        (acc[upperFirst(key)] as unknown) = response[key];
        return acc;
    }, {}) as INodeMailerResponseUpper;
```

Unfortunately, there isn’t a way to completely avoid type assertions.